# If the Universe is expanding, how is that galaxies run into each other?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, galaxies

As the title says. If everything is moving outward, thrown by the Big Bang, how could two Galaxies end up with velocity vectors that run them into each other?

Comment: Just because the universe as a whole is expanding doesn't mean that individual galaxies might not have individual velocity vectors which cause them to collide with each other.

Comment: If my new house is bigger than my old house, how come I still keep running into my wife?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The universe, on a larger scale, is of course expanding, but it doesn't really mean that none of the two galaxies should be allowed to run into each other. Because expansion of the universe is not the only factor that will decide the relative separation between the galaxies. The other major factor which affect the relative separation between the galaxies is the local gravity which can essentially overcome the expansion factor for sufficiently small separation between the galaxies. Such small separation exists in reality and galaxies are evidently running into each other in these cases. The best example may be our galaxy and the Andromeda!

Answer (score -1):

All galaxies are indeed accelerating away from each other, but that doesn't mean that galaxies in their direction won't run into other galaxies.

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong!